# Why doesn't ReactJS component render the state properly with passed in information retrieved from an API call?

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently trying to wrap my head around the following piece of code.

The main reactJS App function is calling an API using Axios to retrieve random data. This data is then passed as a prop to a component called InfoComp.

In the component, InfoComp, we are setting the state, and that state's initial value is the passed in prop.

When InfoComp is rendered, the state is actually undefined, so nothing is rendered. However, if I do "console.log(info)" in InfoComp, the value is actually defined - there is data there. Interestingly, I can even render the prop, info if I do something like:

```
return (
    <div>
      <p>State Value: {JSON.stringify(info)}</p>
    </div>
```

But rendering the state doesn't work even though though I'm initializing the state with the prop, info.

1. Can anyone explain why this is the case?
2. What is the right way in passing information retrieved from an API call as a prop into another component?

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { get_test_api_response } from './api/Provider';
import './App.css';
import InfoComp from './components/InfoComp';

function App() {
  const [info, setInfo] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
      retrieveAndSetInfo();
    }, []);

    const retrieveAndSetInfo = async () => {
        const info_ = await get_test_api_response();

        setInfo(info_);
    }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <InfoComp info={info} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const InfoComp = ( { info } ) => {
  // Using state to store the prop value
  const [infoValue, setInfoValue] = useState(info);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>State Value: {JSON.stringify(infoValue)}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default InfoComp;
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

1. With your code, `infoValue` should actually give you an empty array:

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;
const get_test_api_response = () => new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(
    () => {
      resolve({ foo: 'bar' });
    },
    100
  );
});

const InfoComp = ( { info } ) => {
  console.group();
  console.log('info: %o', info);

  // Using state to store the prop value
  const [infoValue, setInfoValue] = useState(info);
  console.log('infoValue: %o', infoValue);
  console.groupEnd();

  return (
    <div>
      <p>State Value: {JSON.stringify(infoValue)}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  const [info, setInfo] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    retrieveAndSetInfo();
  }, []);

  const retrieveAndSetInfo = () => get_test_api_response().then(info_ => {
    setInfo(info_);
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <InfoComp info={info} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App/>);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

This is because the initialization of the state in `InfoComp` happens **only once** for the entire lifetime of the component. Any changes in the `info` prop after initialization will not be reflected in the state, initial value, since the state has already been initialized within the initialized component.

2. You are passing the data as a prop correctly. You could consider using the `info` prop directly, instead of setting it to a state.

Comment: 1. But I'm simply setting the state in InfoComp to be the prop value itself. If I console.log() the prop, it has the correct data. Shouldn't that imply setting the state's initial value should work in InfoComp?

Comment: 2. This isn't possible for what I'm trying to do. How do people initialize state in a new component then? I'm passing a prop, and it's not initializing the state with that prop's value. Does the issue lie in how I'm fetching the data (from an API) and then passing that to the InfoComp component?

Comment: If I don't fetch the information from an API, but rather hard-code the prop value in the App, then it will render properly in InfoComp. This is what I can't wrap my head around.

Comment: 1. The initial value for the state in `InfoComp` *does* work. At the initial render time of `InfoComp`, `info` in `App` is `[]`, and this is the initialized value of `infoValue` in `InfoComp`. 2. Yes it is possible for what you are trying to do – you are already passing `info` as a prop to `InfoComp`. People initialize state in a new component by passing a value to `useState()`. There is no issue in how you're fetching the data and then passing that to the `InfoComp` component. If you don't fetch the information from an API, but rather hard-code the prop value in the `App`,

Comment: then the value of `info` when `InfoComp` first renders is the data, thus `infoValue` will be this value.

Comment: I'm using useState in InfoComp to set the state based on the passed in prop. Is it there a way to re-render the component so the state value is not [], but rather the prop value? I want to pass prop to InfoComp and also set that as the state in InfoComp, so that when it renders, it displays the state value (not [], but rather than prop value, but from the state itself.)

Comment: Call `setInfoValue()` with the prop.